# Making a word filter (nextcord,python)

Tags: discord, nextcord

How can I make a word filter? I am using nextcord(py) and I would like to make a word filter, but I dont really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

here is a start so you will need to make a list
`words_to_filter = ["wordone", "word2"]`
then we will need to run a loop through the list and get each word
`for word in words_to_filter:`
put this in a on message event:

```
`@client.event()
 async def on_message(self, message):
    for word in words_to_filter:
        if word in message.content
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            await message.channel.send("youve been filtered")`
```